# Building a histogram with haskell, many times slower than with python

Tags: haskell

I was going to test naive bayes classification. One part of it was going to be building a histogram of the training data. The problem is, I am using a large training data, the haskell-cafe mailing list since a couple of years back, and there are over 20k files in the folder.

It takes a while over two minutes to create the histogram with python, and a little over 8 minutes with haskell. I'm using Data.Map (insertWith'), enumerators and text. What else can I do to speed up the program?

Haskell:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TI
import System.Directory
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (filterM, foldM)
import System.FilePath.Posix ((</>))
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Control.Exception.Base (bracket)
import System.IO (Handle, openFile, hClose, hSetEncoding, IOMode(ReadMode), latin1)
import qualified Data.Enumerator as E
import Data.Enumerator (($$), (>==>), (<==<), (==<<), (>>==), ($=), (=$))
import qualified Data.Enumerator.List as EL
import qualified Data.Enumerator.Text as ET



withFile' ::  (Handle -> IO c) -> FilePath -> IO c
withFile' f fp = do
  bracket
    (do
      h ← openFile fp ReadMode
      hSetEncoding h latin1
      return h)
    hClose
    (f)

buildClassHistogram c = do
  files ← filterM doesFileExist =<< map (c </> ) <$> getDirectoryContents c
  foldM fileHistogram M.empty files

fileHistogram m file = withFile' (λh → E.run_ $ enumHist h) file
  where
    enumHist h = ET.enumHandle h $$ EL.fold (λm' l → foldl' (λm'' w → M.insertWith' (const (+1)) w 1 m'') m' $ T.words l) m
```

Python:

```
for filename in listdir(root):
    filepath = root + "/" + filename
    # print(filepath)
    fp = open(filepath, "r", encoding="latin-1")
    for word in fp.read().split():
        if word in histogram:
            histogram[word] = histogram[word]+1
        else:
            histogram[word] = 1
```

**Edit**: Added imports

Comment: What kind of container is `histogram` in Python? It might certainly be reasonable to use a hash map rather than a tree-based one.

Comment: Just the basic dict. I also tried the HashMap from unordered-containers, but the speed lessened and gc time increased.

Comment: Did you compile with -O2? It makes a world of difference.

Comment: Naturally. I always compile with -O2

Comment: The python appears to do 2 lookups for a new key, and 3 for an existing key.  This will probably make the haskell slower by comparison, but Python 2.7 now offers the `collections.Counter` class to support "convenient and rapid tallies".  Just do `histogram = collections.Counter(fp.read().split())`

Comment: can you please add your import declarations to the haskell code?

Comment: Probably won't change the speed, but why not `Map.insertWith' (+) w 1` instead of `Map.insertWith' (const (+1)) w 1`

Comment: Using `Int` instead of `Integer` might also help.

Comment: I just tried to use ByteString.Char8 instead of Text and got a small 20% speedup. Since you're using latin1 anyway ByteString is enough for you here.

Comment: I just checked, and `collections.Counter` is 2x *slower* than the histogram algorithm shown in the OP...

Comment: Can you try a trie instead of a map for the histogram?  Sometimes there's a problem related to retention of data and keys, which using a trie should fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using imperative hash maps from the hashtables package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables
I remember I once got a moderate speedup compared to Data.Map. I wouldn't expect anything spectacular though.

**UPDATE**

I simplified your python code so I could test it on a single big file (100 million lines):

```
import sys
histogram={}
for word in sys.stdin.readlines():
    if word in histogram:
        histogram[word] = histogram[word]+1
    else:
        histogram[word] = 1
print histogram.get("the")
```

Takes 6.06 seconds

Haskell translation using hashtables:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as T
import  qualified Data.HashTable.IO as HT
main = do
  ls <- T.lines `fmap` T.getContents
  h <- HT.new :: IO (HT.BasicHashTable T.ByteString Int)
  flip mapM_ ls $ \w -> do
    r <- HT.lookup h w 
    case r of 
      Nothing -> HT.insert h w (1::Int)
      Just c  -> HT.insert h w (c+1)
  HT.lookup h "the" >>= print
```

Run with a large allocation area: `histogram +RTS -A500M`
Takes 9.3 seconds, with 2.4% GC. Still quite a bit slower than Python but not too bad.

According to the [GHC user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-opts-compile-time), you can change the RTS options while compiling:

> GHC lets you change the default RTS options for a program at compile
>   time, using the -with-rtsopts flag (Section 4.12.6, “Options affecting
>   linking”). A common use for this is to give your program a default
>   heap and/or stack size that is greater than the default. For example,
>   to set -H128m -K64m, link with -with-rtsopts="-H128m -K64m".

Comment: Thank you,this got the time way down. After running the python version today, it takes ~22 seconds (don't know why it took over two minutes consistently yesterday), and haskell version does in 30 seconds with -A500M and 115 seconds without. Can I "embed" the -A500M to the binary somehow?

Comment: @Masse - compile your executable with the flag `-with-rtsopts=-A500M`

Comment: Use histogram[word] += 1 instead of histogram[word] = histogram[word]+1 and python version should be faster. Also if word in histogram slows application down. It should be 
try: histogram[word] += 1 
except KeyError: histogram[world] = 1
or it would be even better to use defaultdict from collections.

Answer (score 7):

Your Haskell and Python implementations are using maps with different complexities. Python dictionaries are hash maps so the expected time for each operation (membership test, lookup, and insertion) is O(1). The Haskell version uses Data.Map which is a balanced binary search tree so the same operations take O(lg n) time. If you change your Haskell version to use a different map implementation, say a hash table or some sort of trie, it should get a lot quicker. However, I'm not familiar enough with the different modules implementing these data structures to say which is best. I'd start with [the Data category on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:data) and look for one that you like. You might also look for a map that allows destructive updates like [STArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-ST.html#t:STArray) does.

Comment: Tried with Data.HashMap from unordered-containers, and the total time was almost the same.

Comment: @Masse did you try without the iteratees and just folding over `fmap words hGetContents`? Also maybe look at [judy arrays](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/09/26/very-fast-scalable-mutable-maps-and-hashes-for-haskell/)

Comment: I think there was about ~60-70% of gc time without iteratees, and ~40-50% with iteratees. Seems like judy arrays only support word-sized keys. Using them in this case would require manual hashing and manually keeping track of buckets. This goes a bit too low-level than I'm willing to go

Comment: I did some benchmarking with different data structures. I tested with Map from containrs, Trie from bytestring-trie, HashTables from hashtables and Hashmap from unordered-containers. The corpus used was a couple of books from project gutenberg, total words 135904 calculated with wc. The results were in order of speed, hashtables (mean 138.2661ms), unordered-containers (160.2763), containers (208.4635ms), bytestring-tries (299.8573ms)

Answer (score 6):

We need more information:

- How long does it take both programs to process the words from the input, with no data structure for maintaining counts?
- How many distinct words are there, so we can judge whether the extra `log N` cost for balanced trees is a consideration?
- What does GHC's profiler say?  In particular, how much time is spent in allocation?  It's possible that the Haskell version is spending most of its time allocating tree nodes that quickly become obsolete.
- **UPDATE**: I missed that lowercase "text" might mean `Data.Text`.  You may be comparing applies and oranges.  Python's Latin1 encoding uses one byte per char.  Although it tries to be efficient, `Data.Text` must allow for the possiblity of more than 256 characters.  What happens if you switch to `String`, or better, `Data.ByteString`?

Depending on what these indicators say, here are a couple of things to try:

- If analyzing the input is a bottleneck, try driving all your I/O and analysis from `Data.ByteString` instead of `Text`.
- If the data structure is a bottleneck, Bentley and Sedgewick's [ternary search trees](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/strings/) are purely functional but perform competetively with hash tables.  There is a `TernaryTrees` package on Hackage.

Comment: Masse said they're using `Text`, not `String`